# V8 javascript for C++ - precompiled binaries

Tags: v8, libv8

Can you please tell me if there are pre-compiled binaries of the v8 library somewhere?

Because building from source is just some kind of hell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

V8 developer here. We do not distribute any official binaries.

Building from source should be quite straightforward using the instructions at https://v8.dev/docs/source-code and https://v8.dev/docs/build-gn.

That said, guessing from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70824928/parsing-scraping-javascript-from-web-in-c-c), you may want to look elsewhere right away, as V8 is not going to help you for that use case: it's a pure ECMAScript engine, so it doesn't know anything about the DOM or related browser functionality. For example, if it saw `document.createElement(...)`, it'd say `ReferenceError: document is not defined`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Let me ask you please, what if М8 saw the string XMLHttpRequest.open ? What would be the result?

Comment: `ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined`. In short, V8 knows these: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference but not these: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API